# PrimeNG p-contextMenu templating

Tags: angular, contextmenu, primeng, templating

I'm using `PrimeNg` controls library. Is there a way to implement a template instead of the common menu item?
All examples that I found on the Internet state that `PrimeNG` users can use only `{icon: xxx, label: uuu}` implementation.

I need checkboxes, dropdowns, images, etc... in my menus.
If it's impossible, can someone point me to the npm package which is *free* and can work with the dynamic templates?